# Install external library (uCrop)

Tags: android

I've found this library to be used with android: https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop

I understand the `Usage` instructions, but as I never used a library before, I don't know how or what should I copy to make run the sample project.

I'll appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-android-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Android Studio, it is very easy to include libraries in your project.

Just find file named build.gradle in app folder, in 
dependencies block add compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0'

```
dependencies {
    //HERE WILL BE SOME ANDROID LIBRARIES

   compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0'
}
```

Comment: But first, should I copy the files in the root directory? (the files extracted in the zip I downloaded from github)

Comment: No, just add this line and gradle will do it for you :)